# Accessing web application hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I have a .net web application which I have hosted on IIS. when I run it, it is working fine. I have assigned the hostname as my static IP address. So i can access my application as http://xxx.xxx.x.x/default.aspx. When I try to access the same address from another computer,I'm not able to access. Am I missing something?

Comment: You could be missing a lot of things. Are they on the same network?

Comment: I could not understand you answer. Did U mean to say LAN. Then definitely  all other PC's r not in the same LAN.

Comment: I didn't post an answer, just a question and and a comment.  Are you able to `ping` the target computer from one of your other computers?

Comment: There are too many possible causes for your question. Networking issues - which is what @shanabus is getting at, security/firewall issues. Also what do you mean "assigned the hostname" as your IP address? If the IP address is public/static your site should be accessible to anyone via http:// the_public_ip_address (there is no "hostname" to set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your machine's IP Address start with: `192.168` (eg: `192.168.1.15`, `192.168.0.35`) or `10.` (eg `10.0.0.45`)?

If so, these are [PRIVATE IP Addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#IPv4_private_addresses), and cannot be accessed from other computers outside your local network.

You would need to configure your router to forward port 80 to your private IP, and then use the address you see on Google when searching for [What is my IP](http://www.google.com/webhp?q=what%20is%20my%20IP)

The details on configuring your router are more suited to [Superuser.com](http://superuser.com) than Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your IP address to the hostname you set.

Say you define your hostname as `thunderbolt.com`

You need to modify your `windows/system32/etc/hosts` file and add the mapping for that hostname to your localhost IP.

Comment: I have given the hostname itself as my IP address